# Android screen video record without root

Tags: android, eclipse, screen, root, record

I want to record a video of the entire screen of my android device and the free apps from google play that can do this require root. Can anyone help with specific steps of what can I do without rooting my phone? Can this be done with Eclipse? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to record the screen output with an attached computer and android studio.

1. Attach the phone to the computer
2. Open Android Studio
3. Look in the Android DDMS view, and click the second icon, the one that looks like a play button (next to the camera button)
4. ???
5. Profit!

But seriously, that's an easy way to do it!

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I work with Eclipse and I'll try your solution. There must be something similar. I'll be back with a reply.

Comment: Coudn't find the video capture function in Eclipse, but as you say it is very easy in the Android Studio. Thanks again!

Comment: on linux my android studio ddms does not have this button :-(

Comment: It's only in  ** Android Studio ** not yet in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can't record the android screen without gaining privileged permissions

Comment: I haven't found this to be the case. I do not have elevated permissions on my Samsung Galaxy SIII nor on my Moto X, Toshiba Thrive, or Google Glass and I can do this on all of my devices. Perhaps it is because I'm working in Mac and Linux, I am not sure.